# Websockets Issue in server

Tags: spring, apache, spring-websocket

When I used https for my webapplication ,Websockets are not working .I used apache as a proxy server.Do Anyone have an idea?
Where exactly the problem is?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Websockets need a support in the browser, which browser are you targeting?

Comment: I think no issues with the browser,When I access the application with "http://ipaddress:port/ProjectName" it is working fine.I think this issue with https and by the way  I'm checking in all the browsers.Every where the problem is same.